What is the distribution of needed hospital beds?

Suppose I am modelling a hospital service with $k$ number of beds.
Initially there are $m$ number of beds being used, where $m \leq k$, each of which has a known amount of time that it has been utilized. The time that a patient has occupied a bed so far is known (i.e. a constant random variable or more simply just a constant).
Demand $D_0^t$ for patients that will require a bed follows a homogenous Poisson point process

$$\alpha_0^t = \int_{0}^t \lambda (t) dt$$
$$D_0^t \sim \text{Poisson}(\alpha_0^t)$$

The length of stay $\text{LoS}$ in a bed for any patient follows a stationary exponential distribution $$\text{LoS} \sim \text{Exponential}(\mu)$$
I am aware of QROT, but I am interested in the probability distribution for needed beds not a bound based on the averages.
I am not interested in a distribution asymptotic in time, but rather the distribution that depends on the interval of time $[0,t]$. This requirement is where I find that a lot of the academic papers I am reading are inapplicable.
Service discipline is non-preemptive EDF.
The deadline (called a benchmark date in this context) for a patient to be put into a bed is defined by the sum of the arrival time of the patient into the queueing area plus a non-negative random variable $B$ with a finite number of outcomes called the benchmark time. The benchmark time distribution is stationary.
A patient requires that a bed is provided to them by their benchmark date, which defines the operational meaning of a needed bed.


Just out of curiosity, do you have real world datasets in the form (hospital, date, occupied=needed beds) and can't you test/fit whatever model/distribution you have in mind against these data? Or do you explicitly care about the modelling steps in-between?
